# forward selection with mixed model using lmer

Tags: lme4-nlme, stepwise-regression

I am running a mixed model in R and would like to perform forward selection using the step function. However, when I set the direction to forward

```
model = lmer(y ~ .)
step(model,direction='forward',scope=biggest)
```

In the output, it states and prints the tables for "backward reduced fixed-effect table" and "backward reduced random-effect table". Why isn't forward selection working?

Comment: voting to close as off-topic (about programming, not statistical aspects). I'm guessing you must be using this method: `?step.lmerModLmerTest`, which only does backward stepwise regression (and silently ignores unused arguments ...)

Answer (score 1):

The most important point here is that forward stepwise selection doesn't work well at all. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/28500), among many others on this site, for why this is a poor strategy. In some circumstances backward stepwise could be considered, but even then the coefficient estimates will be biased and *p*-values will be unreliable.

In any event, the `step()` function uses the [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) to compare among models. The default model fitting method for `lmer()` is REML, which cannot be used for comparisons among mixed models with different fixed effects, as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/116770/28500) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41123/28500). So I'm somewhat surprised that you even got results for a "backward reduced fixed-effect table" and it probably shouldn't be trusted.

In this case, however, this problem with `step` might have saved you from the potentially serious statistical problems that would come from relying on forward stepwise selection.