# Comparing two linear mixed effect models in ANOVA resulting in no p-value

Tags: r

So I need to compare three linear mixed effects models using the `anova` function in R. My advisor oversaw me build the actual models themselves so I am fairly sure the syntax for the models themselves is correct but I get a weird result. Here is my data set for references

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, sub = c("59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956"), subject = c("59917f16e339120001fb8c21", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21"), event = c(68L, 
56L, 72L, 37L, 71L, 48L), timestamp = c("11/24/20 14:27", "11/24/20 14:11", 
"11/24/20 14:27", "11/24/20 14:09", "11/24/20 14:27", "11/24/20 14:10"
), profile = c("mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd"), 
    rating = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L), rt_ms = c(2053L, 2370L, 
    3044L, 1568L, 1112L, 1732L), image = c("accordion_1", "accordion_3", 
    "apple_01", "apple_03", "asian_01", "asian_02"), trial = c(7L, 
    55L, 11L, 36L, 10L, 47L), version = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), onset_s = c(542.394, 418.52, 570.127, 283.328, 563.481, 
    358.924), profile_rating = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), block = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), sub_num = c(179L, 154L, 179L, 154L, 
    179L, 154L), session = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), sub_num2 = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), own_pref = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), 
    cat1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), cat2 = c(2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 
    11L, 11L), item_num = 1:6, learning_run = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L), own_pref_nan = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), profile_rating_new = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), PE = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), PE_si = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), se_PE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), pro_PE = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), mean_p1 = c(3.177631579, 2.868421053, 
    4.421052632, 4.526315789, 4.440789474, 4.0625), mean_p2 = c(2.864197531, 
    2.728395062, 4.283950617, 4.259259259, 3.956790123, 4.104938272
    ), med_p = c(3, 3, 4.5, 5, 5, 5), learn_prof = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I run this data through three models below:

```
td_pref_own <- lmer(rating ~ learn_prof * own_pref * profile_rating_new * profile + (1|sub) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all)
summary(td_pref_own) 

td_pref_mean_adu <- lmer(rating ~ learn_prof * mean_p1 * profile_rating_new * profile + (1|sub) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all)
summary(td_pref_mean_adu) 

td_pref_mean_kid <- lmer(rating ~ learn_prof * mean_p2 * profile_rating_new * profile + (1|sub) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all)
summary(td_pref_mean_kid)
```

Basically, I am replacing the predictors own, mean_p1, and mean_p2 in each model. And then compare the models with this:

```
anova(td_pref_mean_adu, td_pref_own)
anova(td_pref_own, td_pref_mean_kid)
anova(td_pref_mean_adu,td_pref_mean_kid)
```

I get the result below. It seems weird to me that there is no p-value and I'm not really sure how to interpret my results.

```
ata: td_pref_all
Models:
td_pref_mean_adu: rating ~ learn_prof * mean_p1 * profile_rating_new * profile + (1 | sub) + (1 | image)
td_pref_own: rating ~ learn_prof * own_pref * profile_rating_new * profile + (1 | sub) + (1 | image)
                 npar   AIC   BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
td_pref_mean_adu   19 73305 73458 -36634    73267                     
td_pref_own        19 72805 72958 -36384    72767 500.43  0

Data: td_pref_all
Models:
td_pref_own: rating ~ learn_prof * own_pref * profile_rating_new * profile + (1 | sub) + (1 | image)
td_pref_mean_kid: rating ~ learn_prof * mean_p2 * profile_rating_new * profile + (1 | sub) + (1 | image)
                 npar   AIC   BIC logLik deviance Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
td_pref_own        19 72805 72958 -36384    72767                    
td_pref_mean_kid   19 73306 73459 -36634    73268     0  0           

ata: td_pref_all
Models:
td_pref_mean_adu: rating ~ learn_prof * mean_p1 * profile_rating_new * profile + (1 | sub) + (1 | image)
td_pref_mean_kid: rating ~ learn_prof * mean_p2 * profile_rating_new * profile + (1 | sub) + (1 | image)
                 npar   AIC   BIC logLik deviance Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
td_pref_mean_adu   19 73305 73458 -36634    73267                    
td_pref_mean_kid   19 73306 73459 -36634    73268     0  0
```

Does anyone know what this might mean?

Comment: There is an issue with your dataset . I cannot run lmer() function as it throws error referring to your dataset

Comment: I cannot reproduce using `fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)` and `fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)`, then `anova(fm1, fm2)`.

Comment: The models aren't nested, they have the same number of parameters so you can't compare them with ANOVAs like this.  Try asking on Cross-Validated how you might compare them.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are getting the model `td_pref_own` fitted without errors ?  Do you just have the six observations in the data set you shared ?

Comment: Since the models are not nested, I can only assume that you want to compare predictive performance. This usually means that you should focus on cross-validation. Alternatively, it might be sufficient for your purpose to focus on AIC or BIC, both of which indicate that `td_pref_own` appears to be the "best" of the three candidate models.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your three models, the differences are among the fixed terms rather than random terms. On the other hand, the default method of estimation in `lmer()` is REML method which estimates the random effects by removing the fixed effects. Therefore, ML is preferred method of comparison when the fixed effects change which is also true in your case. So my advise is try to  add the input `REML=FALSE` to your `lmer()` call. For more details on choosing ML or REML I would suggest to read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116770/reml-or-ml-to-compare-two-mixed-effects-models-with-differing-fixed-effects-but) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41123/reml-vs-ml-stepaic) posts.

Hope it could helps